# Braintree Client Token Being Decrypted In ERB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, braintree, braintree-rails

I'm using Braintree with Ruby and JS to try and do a basic implementation of the Braintree Drop-In UI.

Here are some relevant code snippets:

Transactions Controller Creating The Token
`@client_token = Braintree::ClientToken`

Page Initializing The Token 
`<script>
 braintree.setup(“<%= @client_token %>”, 'dropin', {
        container: 'checkout'
      }); 
</script>`

And for some reason I end up with the decrypted version of the token. Output looks like this:

```
{"version":1,"authorizationFingerprint":"9802dc7676997d457eb5c656470227a27828f15b12ec4acd3c2cec67782a3001|created_at=2015-03-23T04:29:28.438506721+0000\u0026merchant_id=8gtvngmjy6tmsxz4\u0026public_key=6rp8nrfbvmyfqjf8","configUrl":"
https://api.sandbox.braintreegateway.com:443/merchants/8gtvngmjy6tmsxz4/client_api/v1/configuration
","challenges":["cvv"],"clientApiUrl":"
https://api.sandbox.braintreegateway.com:443/merchants/8gtvngmjy6tmsxz4/client_api
","assetsUrl":"https://assets.braintreegateway.com","authUrl":"
https://auth.venmo.sandbox.braintreegateway.com","analytics":{"url":"
https://client-analytics.sandbox.braintreegateway.com
"},"threeDSecureEnabled":true,"threeDSecure":{"lookupUrl":"
https://api.sandbox.braintreegateway.com:443/merchants/8gtvngmjy6tmsxz4/three_d_secure/lookup
"},"paypalEnabled":true,"paypal":{"displayName":"None","clientId":null,"privacyUrl":"
http://example.com/pp","userAgreementUrl":"http://example.com/tos
","baseUrl":"https://assets.braintreegateway.com","assetsUrl":"
https://checkout.paypal.com
","directBaseUrl":null,"allowHttp":true,"environmentNoNetwork":true,"environment":"offline","unvettedMerchant":false,"braintreeClientId":"masterclient","merchantAccountId":"gbsgnv46xscgk868","currencyIsoCode":"USD"},"coinbaseEnabled":false}"
```

And that is certainly not what the Client Token should look like.

Why am I ending up with the decrypted version?

Comment: It looks like that is an old version of the client token. Which version of `braintree-ruby` are you using? Newer versions of `braintree-ruby` should provide an encoded string instead of json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that is an old version of the client token. Upgrading the gem version will provide you with an encoded client token instead of json.